# Работа с Serial command mode(SCM) MiiNePortE2-H

Tags: c++, микроконтроллеры, uart, atmel-studio

Как настроить `moxa` через данный режим программно? Пытался отправить команду на получение имени платы с `МК(ATXMEGA128A1U)` через `USART`, однако ответа нет, хотя сама команда приходит на `moxa`(смотрел через `IO Ninja`).